# WPDB query what is the cleanest method for a double query?

Tags: sql, wordpress

I am curious as to how best achieve this.

wpdb query 1:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results(
            "SELECT *
            FROM $table_name
            WHERE user_id = '$userid';"
        );
```

I then want to do another wpdb query on a separate table using $results->post_id in the WHERE part of the query such as:

```
$results2 = $wpdb->get_results(
            "SELECT *
            FROM $table_name2
            WHERE user_id = '$results->post_id' && type = '$type';"
        );
```

I am conscious that $results will be an array so I don't think the above will work directly and some sort of compound "for each" seems cumbersome.

What are my options please?

Update example based on Jarlh's comment

```
        $userid = get_current_user_id();
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta';
        $table2_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'posts';
        $rewards_results = $wpdb->get_results(
            "SELECT *
            FROM $table_name
            WHERE post_id in ("SELECT user_id
            FROM $table2_name
            WHERE user_id = '$userid';")"
        );
```

Update 2:

```
        $userid = get_current_user_id();
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta';
        $table2_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'posts';
        $results = $wpdb->get_results(
            "SELECT *
            FROM $table_name
            WHERE ID in (SELECT user_id
            FROM $table2_name
            WHERE user_id = '$userid')"
        );

        //return $results;
        foreach ($results as $row) {
            echo "<td class='dash-2-td'>" . esc_html($row->logo_id) . "</td>";
            echo "<td class='dash-2-td'>" . esc_html($row->belongs_to) . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
```

This is producing no output.

I need to search $table_name->post_id for rows that match $table2_name->ID where user_id = $userid

Update 3: print_r is just showing array(), seems empty

```
        $userid = get_current_user_id();
        global $wpdb;
        //$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta';
        //$table2_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'posts';
        $results = $wpdb->get_results(
            "SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
            FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
            WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
            AND $wpdb->posts.post_author = $userid 
            AND $wpdb->postmeta.plan = 3981
            ");


        return $results;
```

I ended up using wp_query which I had not even considered as an option.

Comment: Is query 1 only used to produce input to query 2?

Comment: Yes that's right.  In plain English - Query 1 = search for all posts belonging to user. Query 2 = of those posts, which ones contain a certain meta key value in another table.

Comment: Do something like `select from t2 where type = $type and user_id in (select user_id from t1 where ...)`

Comment: Please see my update.  It doesn't like the code but is that what you were suggesting?

Comment: `...where user_id in (...`

Comment: Updated it again, it must be close :)

Comment: I ended up using wp_query which I had not even considered as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution, you can use INNER JOIN. Also, I'd suggest you to use $wpdb->prepare for escaping values. Here is an example:

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT a.*, b.col1, b.col2 FROM $table1 as a INNER JOIN $table2 as b ON a.user_id = b.user_id WHERE a.user_id = %d AND b.type = %s", $user_id, $type );
$entries = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, ARRAY_A );
```

Hope it helps.